# Bootstrap - Why is a div with a lower z-index covering a higher one?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, z-index

A `position:fixed` div covers the entire page (except for elements with higher z-indexes, like the `<a></a>` elements).

Or at least, that is unless you click the navbar brand name, which I set to `z-index: 9999;` while the entire page div is `z-index:9994`.

Once the `position:fixed` div is clicked, it closes the dropdown menu.

The `position:fixed` div only appears when the dropdown menu is open. It's class name is `.blackout` and it's container name is `.labelBlackout`.

You can make .labelBlackout appear by clicking the "Solutions" dropdown.
Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tsb3zthn/

How can I make the navbar brand name clickable while the `position:fixed`div is active?

Thank you so much! <3

```
  <style>
/* THIS IS WHERE THE DROPDOWN MENU CODE STARTS */
  .buttoncontainer1 { /*A wrapper for your hover dropdown List*/
  height:49px;
  float:left;
  position:relative;  
  z-index:9995;
  }
  .mycheckButton { /*Your Label acts as a Button Triggering the checkbox*/
  height:49px;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  background-color:#f8f8f8;
  text-align:center;
  color:#777;
  position:relative; 
  z-index:9995;
  cursor:pointer;
  }
  .mycheckDrop { /*Your Dropdown*/
  width:88px;
  float:left;
  display:none;
  background-color:#f8f8f8;
  position:fixed; 
  z-index:9996;
  margin-top:50px;
  }

  .gone { /*Make your checkbox disappear*/
  border:0px;
  outline:none;
  line-height:0;
  display:none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  width:0px;
  height:0px;
  }
  .blackout { /*This Div covers the page with the labelBlackout Label in it. nothing can be clicked unless The Label inside clicked first triggering the checkbox. */
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  float:left;
  position:fixed;
  background-color:black; opacity:0.7; /*    You can add a background color like this. background-color:black; opacity:0.7;*/
  display:none;
  z-index: 9994;
  }  
  .labelBlackout { /*the Label inside the blackout div that covers the page*/
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
  float:left; 
  z-index: 9994
  }  
  .lnkCon {    /*  Container that holds your dropdown links.*/
  width:100%;
  height:49px;
  float:left;
  }
  label {
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  input[type=checkbox].gone:checked ~ div.blackout{display:block;}  
  input[type=checkbox].gone:checked ~ label.mycheckDrop{display:block;}    
  .buttoncontainer1:hover > .mycheckDrop{display:block;}

  a {
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999;
    }
  .buttoncontainer1{cursor:pointer;}
  input{cursor:pointer;}
  .navbar-brand {
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  div.navbar-brand {
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  div.navbar-header {
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  </style>

<body>
  <div class="navbar-header"> 

    <label type="button" for="navbar-toggle-cbox" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </label> 

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MiracleShack</a></div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse center">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav topnav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <div class="buttoncontainer1">
              <input class="gone" id="myCheck" type="checkbox" >
              <div class="blackout" >
              <label class="labelBlackout" for="myCheck"></label></div>
              <label class="mycheckButton" for="myCheck">Solutions</label>
              <label class="mycheckDrop" for="myCheck">
              <span class="lnkCon"><a href="#">Button 1</a></span>
              <span class="lnkCon"><a href="#">Button 2</a></span>
              <span class="lnkCon"><a href="#">button 3</a></span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <li class=""><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to your .navbar-brand class

z-index only works on positioned elements. If you try to set a z-index on an element with no position specified, it will do nothing

https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 3):

There is one css rule missing to reach what you want, you have to add:

```
.navbar-header {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
}
```

because as @jndoy mentioned **z-index only works on positioned elements**.

Check the updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsb3zthn/1/).

Hope this helps :)